# How to use third-party javascript library (pixijs) in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, pixi.js

Hi all I am new to `Angular JS` and `Ionic Framework`,  I am learning both using the latest version, **`angular2`** and **`ionic2`**.

I want to use **[PixiJs](http://www.pixijs.com/)**`(2D webGL renderer)` in my app, but I dont know **how to add a third-party javascript library into Ionic2 app**.

following I have tried:

1. Installed the third-party library

   > **`npm install pixi --save`**
2. Imported

   > **`import {PIXI} from 'pixi';`**
3. Using

   > **`var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);`**

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stage' of undefined`

Please help me.

Comment: Do you know how to add a third-party JavaScript library to a web page?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same way like putting it in the head tag using script tag. But then ionic is throwing lot of error, mainly PIXI is undefined.

Comment: I am expecting there should be way to add it via npm installer and use it, but not working what all I am trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally resolved with this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) on [Include External JavaScript Libraries In An Angular 2 TypeScript Project](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) by **Nic Raboy**.

> It says to include the script in the html header as usual web applications, then in the ts file where we need the variable declare it as follow,
>
> **`declare var libraryVar: any;`**
> Then use this libraryVar where ever we need.

Comment: I just wanted to add. You may `npm install @types/pixi.js` to get real declarations.